# How to access an Oracle 9.2 *and* Oracle 12c DB with Kotlin running on Java 10+?

Tags: java, oracle, kotlin, oracle12c, oracle9i

I'm developing an application, written in Kotlin on JDK 10+, that has to:

- access a legacy Oracle DB version 9.2
- stores the data on Oracle DB 12c

Is there anyway in which a JDK 10+ application can connect to Oracle 9.2? I cannot find any driver whatsoever that supports Oracle 9.2 even for JDK 8...

Alternatively is it somehow possible to configure DB link between the 12c and the 9.2 DBs? I know that some features may not be supported, but we aren't going to need advanced stuff so even if it is not officially supported if the authentication for the DB link works and basic queries works it should be enough for us.

---

Note:

- it is impossible to upgrade the legacy DB. There are literally hundreds of other legacy systems that access that DB.
- The security groups for our client wont probably allow deploying completely outdated JDKs like 1.6/1.7.... *maybe* they could allow 1.8...
- Yes, they should have kept updating the stuff years and years and years ago, we already know that.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle JDBC 9.2 is not supported. You must upgrade to latest versions. Check out [FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html) for the JDK versions supported by different versions of the driver.

Answer (score 0):

A customer that still runs on 9.2 is not interested in security at all. An oracle certified solution won't be available but a solution that works ..... almost certainly does exits (just looking at driver dbms inter operability, not so much to the JDK.

Aim for the 11gR2 JDBC drivers. They will work with both versions of databases (9.2 and 12c). Even 12c is going out of support ver soon so the step to v19 is already on the horizon I hope.

Sorry I can be no more precise, I lost it on the Java part....